# Android class member "fields" understanding

Tags: android, field

I'm new to Android(and Java also) and I'm trying to understand what are Fields in predefined Android classes.

For example in the Android View class there are Fileds: EMPTY_STATE_SET, ENABLED_FOCUSED_SELECTED_STATE_SET etc.
Please can you tell me how to understand this and how can I use it? For me it looks like some constants but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically they are constants for the class, to be used in situations like this:

```
myWidget.setColor(Widget.BLACK_AND_TAN);
```

They usually have integer values, but they make the code more readable this way, and also allow for later changes to the API without altering the behavior of previous code. (`Widgets.BLACK_AND_TAN == 7`, or `Widgets.BLACK_AND_TAN ==15`,could both be true, or any other number.  It doesn't matter.  Just that `BLACK_AND_TAN` always corresponds to Black and Tan coloring.)

edit: note that Widget is a made up class, as is the `BLACK_AND_TAN` constant.  let me get a real example for you.

Real Example, used to re-position the cursor every time a text field is updated:

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)outputArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

Note that these do not HAVE to be constants as we normally refer to them;  for example

```
Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
```

can be user defined, but it does specify how long a toast should display

Comment: Thanks for explanation. 

But why is for example this field:
'protected static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET'

defined as a field? 
Why it's not defined as a Constant?

Comment: in Java that IS a constant.  `static` means it has a universal value across all instances of the class, and `final` means that, once a value HAS been written to the field, it cannot be changed.

Comment: But I don't understand why there are field culomns [].

Comment: In this case, a STATE is passed to `Drawable(int[] state)` later, defining the characteristics of how that  object should be drawn. 

Look at it as a flag for the View to assume all of the field values necessary for it to be drawn as it once when empty.

Edit:

The [] indicate that it is an array of ints, of course.  I've been assuming you knew that.  Is that true?